# Is $(\omega \times \omega)^{\omega}\cong \omega \times \omega \times... \cong \omega^{\omega}$? Where "$\cong$" means homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, products, infinite-product

I'm interested in the circumstances for when we can conclude that two ordinal spaces are homeomorphic by an examination of their written form.  Specifically, I'm taking an ordinal space, say $(\omega^2)$, and considering the $\omega$ power.

For example, from the title, is

$(\omega \times \omega)^{\omega}\cong (\omega \times \omega) \times (\omega \times \omega) \times... \ \cong \ (\omega \times \omega \times ...) \ \cong \ \omega^{\omega}$?

On one hand, we can analyze the function spaces and determine if they are homeomorphic.  I'm wondering is there some sort of "algebra" that I can use in this type of context.

Comment: Are you asking about the ordinal space $\omega^2$ or the product space $\omega \times \omega$? Note that the latter is discrete, while the former is not. (Ordinal multiplication is virtually never denoted with $\times$.)

Comment: Your notation is unfortunate. Of course, in the example you're discussing, exponentiation is ambiguous. As @purplemonkeydishwasher says, ordinal multiplication is never denoted by $\times$, which in this context can only mean Cartesian product. So stick to $\omega^2$ for the basic space. Now, exponentiation to $\omega$ will be ambiguous — completely so, in your rightmost expression, Do you mean $\omega^{\omega}$ to be ordinal exponentiation, or $\omega$ many products? Suggestion: use $X^{\Bbb N}$ for the $\omega$-fold Cartesian product. Your leftmost term would then be $(\omega^2)^{\Bbb N}$.